# How do I convert Excel General Text to Date?

Tags: excel, vba, date

My problem is I have a Date that is defined as General in Excel as "10 JUL 2021 10:30". I want to make it Excel Date.

Kindly have a look at my picture for detailed understanding.

I need any kind of solution to automate this VBA or any formula.

Comment: A _date/time_ value is that - applied a (default) format for display. There is no special "Excel date". What could it be?

Comment: Excel as this "10 JUL 2021 10:30, I want to Make it like 7/10/2021. But I cant change it from simple data type of excel, "10 JUL 2021 10:30 it is recognized as string and cant do formula work when it is recognized as string

Answer (score 0):

I just tried using the `DateValue()` worksheet function, and every worked fine (normal Excel formula, no VBA needed):

```
=DATEVALUE("07 JUL 2021 10:30")
```

One thing that might be interesting for you: there exists a cell formatting (`dd mmm yyyy hh:mm`), which you seem to be using. (When you apply this on any cell, the value inside gets automatically formatted into that kind of date format.)

**Edit, based on comment:**

In case there's a comma in your date string, remove it first and then apply the `DateValue()` function:

```
=DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE("07 JUL 2021, 10:30",",",""))
```

Comment: The problem is there is a comma between date and time its like "07 JUL 2021, 10:30"

Comment: @SanjibSamadder: that comma is not in your question (you mention a picture, but I don't see anything). nevertheless it's not a big problem to remove that comma and use `DateValue()` afterwards. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you need VBA to extract Date, please use the next function:

```
Function TextToDateX(txt As String) As Date
   Dim arrD, arrM
   arrM = Split("JAN,FEB,MAR,APR,MAY,JUN,JUL,AUG,SEP,OCT,NOV,DEC", ",")
  
   arrD = Split(txt, " ")
   TextToDateX = DateSerial(CLng(arrD(2)), Application.match(arrD(1), arrM, 0), CLng(arrD(0))) + CVDate(arrD(3))
End Function
```

It can be tested as:

```
Sub testTextToDateX()
    Dim txt As String, d As Date
     txt = "10 JUL 2021 10:30"
     
    d = TextToDateX(txt)
    Debug.Print Format(d, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm")
End Sub
```

`DateValue` is localization related. Microsoft states: "DateValue recognizes the order for month, day, and year according to the Short Date format that you specified for your system". So, it may work or not.

In my case it doesn't...